# Calendar component not rendering

Tags: primefaces

I just started working with primefaces. To display calendar, I created the dateBean with a java.util.date variable and used the following line in the xhtml. But I am only getting the textfileld part of the calendar and the calendar component is not getting displayed. I don't know much about themes. As of now my xhtml file does not use any theme either default or custom. My web-inf\lib has the following jar files.

jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, jstl.jar, primefaces-2.2.1.jar

index.xhtml -

```
<p:calendar rendered="true" id="calendar" value="#{dateBean.curDate}" mode="inline" />
```

Thanks and Regards,
Renju

Comment: can you post your dateBean and xhtml code

Answer (score 1):

the 'rendered' attribute is not necessary, since default is true.
the "inline" mode doesn't show a textfield, it only displays the calendar, so it's very strange that you see a textfield.
Did you try displaying in another way to see if it works? for example:

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" value="#{dateBean.curDate}" showOn="button"/>
```

maybe bean code and some more of the xhtml would be helpful to find out what's wrong.
Regards

Comment: Thank you for yur kind reply.I found out the problem, it was with JSF version. I was using conflicting versions of JSF and prime faces. Now I rectified that and the calendar is appearing. I don't want to use the default theme so I disabled it in web.xml giving primeface.theme as none. Now the problem is, after doing this, my calendar appearence changed. The navigtor buttons Prev and Next are not displayed and the calendar is not having boreder also. How to rectify this? Is there any way where I can use the default theme only for the calendar or I should create my own theme for the calendar?

Comment: Hello Renju, Post another question and I'll be happy to help you.
in the meantime, did you include navigator="true" attribute?
Regards